# Calling np.array on a list of RandomForestRegressors returns an array of DecisionTreeRegressors

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

When I try to convert a list of RandomForestRegressors to a numpy array, I get an array of Decision Trees.  How do I get an array of RandomForestRegressors instead?

e.g.

```
clf0=RandomForestRegressor()
clf1=RandomForestRegressor()

X = np.random.randn(10,1)
y = np.random.randn(10,1)

clf0.fit(X,y)
clf1.fit(X,y)

m = np.array( [clf0, clf1 ] )

m.shape

Out[1]: (2, 10)
```

I want m.shape to be (2,), not (2,10).  And it should contrain RandomForestRegressors, not DecisionTreeRegressors.

Comment: What happens if you use `dtype=object` in `np.array`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using dtype=object or dtype=RandomForestRegressor does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

This was recently answered on the scikit-learn mailing list: a random forest behaves as [sequence](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-sequence) of decision trees:

```
>>> len(clf0)
10
>>> clf0[:2]
[DecisionTreeRegressor(compute_importances=None, criterion='mse',
           max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
           random_state=1087328618, splitter='best'),
 DecisionTreeRegressor(compute_importances=None, criterion='mse',
           max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
           random_state=357905606, splitter='best')]
```

NumPy picks this up and converts the RFs themselves to arrays. The workaround is easy:

```
>>> m = np.empty(2, object)
>>> m[:] = clf0, clf1
>>> m
array([ RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, compute_importances=None,
           criterion='mse', max_depth=None, max_features='auto',
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
           min_samples_split=2, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
           random_state=None, verbose=0),
       RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, compute_importances=None,
           criterion='mse', max_depth=None, max_features='auto',
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
           min_samples_split=2, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
           random_state=None, verbose=0)], dtype=object)
```

(Mind you, your `y` has the wrong shape. It should be `(10,)`, not `(10, 1)`.)

Comment: Is there a way to turn your two lines into a single list comprehension?

Comment: @user847663: I don't think so.